# How can I control the order in which event handlers are fired?

Tags: .net, events

Are event handlers fired in the order that they attached to the event? If not, can I enforce some kind of order onto the event handlers such that they are called in a specific order?

Comment: Event handlers that have to be called in a specific order? Sounds like a code smell to me. If you have to ask this question anyone maintaining your code will have to ask it as well making for hard to maintain code. Can you tell us why you want to do this please so we can suggest a better design.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Following article explains how to do that http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b81385/how-to-change-order-of-event-handlers-execution-at-run-time/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming a simple implementation of the event (using += and -= on a delegate field, which in turn will use `Delegate.Combine/Remove`) then yes, the event handlers will be called in the order in which they're subscribed. The guarantee is effectively given in the [`Delegate.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326800.aspx) documentation:

> **Return value**
>
> A new multicast (combinable) delegate
>   with an invocation list that
>   concatenates the invocation lists of *a*
>   and *b* in that order.

See my [article about events](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html) for some examples of which `Delegate.Combine/Remove` do (and what events are like under the covers).

Answer (score 4):

*Do **NOT** rely on event ordering*. All event dispatches should be logically independent, as if they were occurring in parallel.

The addition of event handlers in other classes and threads may disturb your assumed ordering, this is just not a safe assumption to make, and it goes against the concept of events as independent decoupled actions.

I'll go one step further, and assert that if you have to assume an order for events firing, you have a serious design flaw and/or are misusing events.

Answer (score 2):

You might have one event handler that calls other functions or delegates in a specified order.

Comment: Or depending on the case, use different events for each action.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend "wrapping it."

Do something like this...

```
MyObject.MyEvent += new MyEventHandler(Wrapper);

public void Wrapper()
{
    Method1();
    Method3();
    Method2();
}
```

That way you're still hooking the event but have complete control of what's called.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply.

---

I've come across with a situation that I have to deal with order of eventhandlers.

I have a form, and when I click a button on the form, a object is added into a collection somewhere in my code.

The collection has a "Added" event, and two delegates have been hooked to it. One of the method deletes any item just added into the collection, while the other one shows message to user.

---

If I have some code shows here, a "IndexOutOfRange" exception would be thrown when the event is triggered:

```
// this methods hooks two delegates to MyCollection.Added event, but the order results in a "IndexOutOfRange" exception after the event is triggered
HookEvents()
{
   MyCollection.Added += new CollectionItemAddedHandler(DeleteItem_After_CollectionItemAdded);

   MyCollection.Added += new CollectionItemAddedHandler(ShowMessage_After_CollectionItemAdded);
}


// when user click a button on form, add a object to MyCollection
Button_Clicked()
{
   MyCollection.Add(new object());     
}

// at the moment a object is added into the collection, this method remove it
DeleteItem_After_CollectionItemAdded(NewIndexArgs e)
{
    MyCollection.Remove(e.NewIndex); // e.NewIndex represents the newly added item index in current collection  
}

// at the moment a object is added into the collection, this method show its information (hey, but remember, I just remove it in the previous method)
ShowMessage_After_CollectionItemAdded(NewIndexArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(MyCollection[e.NewIndex]); // tell user what is just added into the current collection
    // a "IndexOutOfRange" exception is thrown here....
}
```

---

What will make this scenario work **correctly** is that the "ShowMessage_After_CollectionItemAdded" method should be triggered **first**, and then it'd be the "DeleteItem_After_CollectionAdded" method.

Although we can += the "ShowMessage..." method first, there's sometimes **we can't predefine this sequence until runtime**.