# Logging for each method in "delegate"

Tags: c#, .net

I have a delegate:

```
private delegate void ActivitySteps(string inputFolder, string outputFolder);
```

In one of the methods in my class I register various activities to it :

```
this.activitySteps = A;
this.activitySteps += B;
```

and so on...

Finally I invoke it :

```
this.activitySteps.Invoke(inputFolder, outputFolder);
```

Now I want to add logging so that I know which of the event i.e. method failed while invoking the delegate. (A or B or some other).
Is there a way I could do that so that I don't have to log in each method and could centralize the logging within delegate.

Comment: Where are you actually having problems? Knowing how to create a log or adding to that log? You would just either create a new logger in each delegate or pass one in if you are writing to a single log.

Comment: I want to add logging information at one place while invoking the delegate so that I don't have to replicate the logging in all the methods.

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/374549/284111). Continuing where it started I would suggest reworking your logic to not rely on delegates order.

Comment: @Andrew Savinykh My Logic Doesn't depend upon the delegation order. I was just trying to get information that which step actually failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `GetInvocationList()` when invoking the delegates:

```
foreach( ActivitySteps del in this.activitySteps.GetInvocationList() )
{
    try
    {
        del.Invoke( inputFolder, outputFolder );
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0} threw {1}", del.Method.Name, ex );
    }
}
```